# body pseudo element 100% height of Document

Tags: html, css

I am trying to force a pseudo element of the `<body>` element to always be 100% height of the `Document` (not window).

- `position` of the *pseudo* element ***must not*** be set to `FIXED`
- This is only a simplified version to a problem i'm having, so the solution must be CSS only

**[DEMO PAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/rkYDv/1/)**

I have searched **stack overflow** and have found no answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
html {height: 100%;}
body {min-height:100%;}
```

and then your existing code:

```
body{ position:relative; }
p{ width:15%; padding:10px; }

body::before {
    background: red;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
    opacity: 0.2;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

​